# Ruby - Graph adjacency matrix into variable

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, algorithm

I am trying to edit an algorithm found [here](https://gist.github.com/gosuri/5126638).

I want the adjacency matrix to be loaded from file (formatting of the file doesn't matter to me, it can be either like this `[0,1,1,0]` or just `0110`) with `G = file.read().split("\n")`

However, I get an error `no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)`
And I already know I need to convert this string to ints, but how to do it properly to not lose the formatting required by this DFS method?

I guess it's pretty easy, but I'm a begginer in Ruby (and graphs :v) and can't get it to work...

Edit:
So the code I'm using to read from file to an array of arrays is:

```
def read_array(file_path)
  File.foreach(file_path).with_object([]) do |line, result|
    result << line.split.map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

And the result I get from a file (for example)

```
01101010
01010101
01010110
10101011
01011111
```

is this:

```
=> [[[1101010], [1010101], [1010110], [10101011], [1011111]]]
```

What I need, however, is:

```
=> [[[1,1,0,1,0,1,0], [1,0,1,0,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0,1,1,0], [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], [1,0,1,1,1,1,1]]]
```

So that it would work with the algorithm mentioned in the first line of my post (I'll copy it here, if it takes too much place I can delete it and leave link only):

```
G = [0,1,1,0,0,1,1], # A
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
[1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0] # G

LABLES = %w(A B C D E F G)

def dfs(vertex)

  print "#{LABLES[vertex]} " # visited

  edge = 0
  while edge < G.size
    G[vertex][edge] = 0
    edge += 1
  end

  edge = 0
  while edge < G.size
    if ( G[edge][vertex] != 0 && edge != vertex)
      dfs(edge)
    end
    edge += 1
  end
end

dfs(0)
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what you’re trying to do, what you expect to happen and what you actually see. Can you provide a minimal code example that produces the error?

Comment: @matt so I edited the post, if I omitted sth else please tell. Basically I just want this code to work with any graph adjacency matrix loaded from file, not hard-coded into .rb file.

Oh, and the error I provided I received when I tried to just load a file containing what I wanted 'G' to be.

Comment: The result you show is an array containing a single array containing several arrays. Is that right or a typo? In other words should it be `[[1101010], ... [1011111]]` instead of `[[[1101010], ... [1011111]]]`?

Comment: @matt I missed that - but what it prints actually is [[[101010], ...]]], and I guess it should be [[101010], ... ]], so I could simply use it with the function mentioned.

Comment: The method you show results in the singly wrapped array. You must be wrapping the result in another array somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split)'s default separator is a whitespace. To make it split every char you need to explicitly say it:

```
'01101101'.split.map(&:to_i)
# => [ 1101101 ]
'01101101'.split('').map(&:to_i)
# => [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
```

you can also use [`chars`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-chars) to do the same job:

```
'01101101'.chars.map(&:to_i)
# => [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 ]
```

---

I don't know how your `read_array` is used, but it can be simplified to:

```
def read_array(file_path)
  File.foreach(file_path).map do |line|
    line.chomp.chars.map(&:to_i)
  end
end

read_array('my_file.txt')
# => [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

If you still get the extra `[`, you can either take only the first item:

```
my_array[0]
```

Or (if there is more than one item the uber-array) - use `flat_map`:

```
uber_array = [[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]],
             [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]

uber_array.flat_map { |a| a }
# => [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: I still get `[[[` instead of `[[` opening and ending brackets. Any way to fix that? When using this with my DFS algorithm it only prints two vertexes

Comment: I'm really sorry, my mistake - I've been using a .txt file with commas and brackets already entered - there is no need to delete the extra brackets when using a file formatted like this `010101\n010101`